# issue with print function in python

Tags: python

I have a line of code:

```py
print('some text, ' + generic_text_1 + ', ' + generic_text_2 + generic_text_3)
```

The output is `some text, generic_text_1, generic_text_2 generic_text_3`, but I want it to be:

```py
some text,
generic_text_1
generic_text_2
generic_text_3
```

I tried to change the structure to

```py
print( 
'some text, '
+ generic_text_1 + ', ' 
+ generic_text_2 
+ generic_text_3)
```

But it didn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: The end of a line is indicated by a newline character, which also advances the cursor to the start of the following line. Using the escape character \n , we can print a newline in Python

Comment: hi

so you suggest something like that:
print( 'some text', '\n', generic_text_1,'\n',  generic_text_2,'\n', generic_text_3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sep` argument for that:

```py
print('some text', generic_text_1, generic_text_2, generic_text_3, sep='\n')
```

will result to

```py
some text
(the value of the variable generic_text_1)
(the value of the variable generic_text_2)
(the value of the variable generic_text_3)
```

---

If it doesn't work, put `generic_text_1`, `generic_text_2` and `generic_text_3` in brackets `"`, because they might not be variables.

Comment: thank you @stysan this is so much cleaner and easier!
p.sgeneric_texts are variables

Comment: don't mention it, glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass many strings as arguments to the `print` function they will appear side to side unless you pass the keyword argument `sep` as `sep = "\n"`

like this:

```
>print( 'some text', generic_text_1, generic_text_2, generic_text_3, sep= "\n")
some text,
generic_text_1
generic_text_2
generic_text_3
```

if you need the comma than you could use the + operator togheter with the `", "` string like

```
>print( 'some text', generic_text_1 + ", ", generic_text_2 + ", ", generic_text_3, sep= "\n")
some text,
generic_text_1,
generic_text_2,
generic_text_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code that will output:

> some text, generic_text_1, generic_text_2 generic_text_3

```
print('some text, ' + 'generic_text_1, ' + 'generic_text_2 ' + 'generic_text_3')
```

The code that will output:
some text,

generic_text_1,

generic_text_2,

generic_text_3

```
print('some text,\ngeneric_text_1,\ngeneric_text_2,\ngeneric_text_3')
```

The \n will create a space.

There are different types of end for print.
[End Parameter for Print](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/)

You can also check out the python documentation for "print" function or other built in functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't inserted any newlines. Your second example is close to what you want, except that the newlines are not part of the strings themselves, so also don't appear. Instead, you can use multiline f-strings.

You embed the variable references in the text and their newlines are included in the string. The text in the .py file looks like the final text you want. Notice the backslash after the opening quote - it escapes the first newline, so it's not in the final string.

```
generic_text_1 = "generic_text_1"
generic_text_2 = "generic_text_2"
generic_text_3 = "generic_text_3"

print(f"""\
some text,
{generic_text_1}
{generic_text_2}
{generic_text_3}""")
```

Answer (score -1):

the issue you're facing is because python concatenates all the **`strings`** together before passing them to the **`print`** function, resulting in the variables being concatenated into a single **`string`**, and that's why they appear on the same line.

To solve this problem, there are several ways you can do it.

You can use multiple print statements like this:

```
print('some text, ')
print(generic_text_1)
print(generic_text_2)
print(generic_text_3)
```

This will generate the output:

```
some text, 
Generic Text 1
Generic Text 2
Generic Text 3
```

Alternatively, you can use the `sep` argument, which will be used like this:

```
print('some text,', generic_text_1, generic_text_2, generic_text_3, sep='\n')
```

This will generate the same output:

```
some text,
Generic Text 1
Generic Text 2
Generic Text 3
```

If you wish, you can also find more information in the [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) documentation